# Move a file to a different drive with Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to move a file from my C-drive to my H-drive using os.Replace().

The code looks as follows:

```
func MoveFile(source string, destination string) {
    err := os.Rename(source, destination)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
rename C:\old\path\to\file.txt H:\new\path\to\file.txt: The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive.
```

I found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13766) issue on GitHub that specifies the problem but it appears that they will not change this function to allow it to move file on different disk drives.

I already searched for other possibilities to move files, but found nothing in the standard documentation or the internet.

So, what should I do now to be able to move files on different disk drives?

Comment: Well, that should be pretty obvious: You copy the file to the new location (crating a new file) and delete the old once the copy has been written successfully.

Comment: Ok, but go does not seem to provide a way to copy files, I could find nothing in the os package. Or do I need to create my own copy function in which I create a whole new file and use streams or so the copy the data?

Comment: Yes, and that is totally trivial (like 2 lines) for small files and only slightly more complicated for larger ones.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the comment said, you'll need to create a new file on the other disk, copy the contents, and then remove the original.  It's straightforward using `os.Open`, `os.Create`, `io.Copy`, and `os.Remove`:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func MoveFile(sourcePath, destPath string) error {
    inputFile, err := os.Open(sourcePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open source file: %v", err)
    }
    defer inputFile.Close()

    outputFile, err := os.Create(destPath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open dest file: %v", err)
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(outputFile, inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't copy to dest from source: %v", err)
    }

    inputFile.Close() // for Windows, close before trying to remove: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64943554/246801

    err = os.Remove(sourcePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't remove source file: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, based on the comment of @volker, I created a similar function using `ioutil.ReadFile`, `ioutil.WriteFile` and `os.Remove`
Are these good as well, or is your version better?

Comment: Using `ioutil.ReadFile` is generally fine for smaller files, but it does copy the entire file into a slice. This means means that "moving" a large file will take lots of memory if you use those functions.  The version I posted, using `io.Copy` does not require reading the entire file into memory at a time, and should be better for large files and keeping memory usage down.

If you don't care about huge files, then just do whatever's simpler, but in general I'd recommend using `io.Copy` for this--it's meant for cases like yours, where you don't need to modify the data before writing it.

Comment: `io.Copy` can even make use of kernel-specific syscalls that avoid loading the file into userspace at all. You should use `io.Copy`.

Comment: @Vhitewidow: `ioutil.` ReadFile` reads the entire file into memory at one time. It's only good for small filles.

Comment: That doesn't deal with ownership or permissions

Comment: There's a bug here. If the input file can be opened but the output file can't, the file descriptor for the input file will never be closed. You should add `defer inputFile.Close()` after the input error check.

Comment: @Vhitewidow, and anybody else, ioutil was deprecated in Go 1.16 (Feb 2021) in favor of implementations in the io and os packages, <https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil>.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you handle all cases on both Linux and Windows. For example, for any size file,

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func MoveFile(source, destination string) (err error) {
    src, err := os.Open(source)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer src.Close()
    fi, err := src.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    flag := os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREATE | os.O_TRUNC
    perm := fi.Mode() & os.ModePerm
    dst, err := os.OpenFile(destination, flag, perm)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer dst.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)
    if err != nil {
        dst.Close()
        os.Remove(destination)
        return err
    }
    err = dst.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = src.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = os.Remove(source)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var src, dst string
    flag.StringVar(&src, "src", "", "source file")
    flag.StringVar(&dst, "dst", "", "destination file")
    flag.Parse()
    if src == "" || dst == "" {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err := MoveFile(src, dst)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("moved %q to %q\n", src, dst)
}
```

Output (Linux):

```
$ cp move.file src.file && go build movefile.go && ./movefile -src=src.file -dst=dst.file
moved "src.file" to "dst.file"
$
```

Output (Windows):

```
>copy /Y move.file src.file && go build movefile.go && movefile -src=src.file -dst=dst.file
moved "src.file" to "dst.file"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution **Moves** the file and preserves permissions:

```
func MoveFile(src, dst string) error {
    in, err := os.Open(src)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open source file: %s", err)
    }

    out, err := os.Create(dst)
    if err != nil {
        in.Close()
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open dest file: %s", err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, in)
    in.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Writing to output file failed: %s", err)
    }

    err = out.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Sync error: %s", err)
    }

    si, err := os.Stat(src)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Stat error: %s", err)
    }
    err = os.Chmod(dst, si.Mode())
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Chmod error: %s", err)
    }

    err = os.Remove(src)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed removing original file: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

If only want to **Copy** the file without remove the original:

```
func CopyFile(src, dst string) error {
    in, err := os.Open(src)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open source file: %s", err)
    }

    out, err := os.Create(dst)
    if err != nil {
        in.Close()
        return fmt.Errorf("Couldn't open dest file: %s", err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, in)
    in.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Writing to output file failed: %s", err)
    }

    err = out.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Sync error: %s", err)
    }

    si, err := os.Stat(src)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Stat error: %s", err)
    }
    err = os.Chmod(dst, si.Mode())
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Chmod error: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a magic approach, just using the `syscall.MoveFile` as follows.

```golang
func main() {
    oldpath := "D:\\black.txt"
    newpath := "E:\\black-new.txt"

    from, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(oldpath)
    to, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(newpath)
    fmt.Println(*from, *to)
    err := syscall.MoveFile(from, to)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

the program works.

if you want a cross-platform compatibility program, you can implement your own `MoveFile`.

```golang
func MoveFile(src string, dst string) error {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        from, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(src)
        to, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(dst)
        return syscall.MoveFile(from, to)
    } else {
        return os.Rename(src, dst)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I compile this on linux it complains about all the syscalls undefined: syscall.UTF16PtrFromString, undefined: syscall.UTF16PtrFromString, undefined: syscall.MoveFile