# Should you close temporarily created files or can you directly delete them?

Tags: file, go

If you have a file which is created temporarily for some purpose in the scope of a single function and its removal is deferred at the end of the function, should you take care of closing the temporary file before removing it or does `os.Remove()` take care of releasing all associated resources?

```
func foo() error {
    tempFile, err := os.Create(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        /* Is this necessary?
            if err = tempFile.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Error(err)
                return
            }
        */

        if err = os.Remove(filePath); err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }
    }()

    // do something

    return nil
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go.

Comment: From what I have observed, on most platforms `Remove()` will simply "unlink" the file, which means you can no longer open it, but existing handles can still read it without problems until they are closed. Only after that may the OS forget entirely about the file's contents (whatever that means). So yes, you should always close handles when you no longer need them. On some platforms, you *may* have to do so before trying to remove it. If you need more rigorous control over this behavior, you'll find advanced APIs for that in most OSs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should you take care of closing the temporary file before removing it or does `os.Remove()` take care of that?

"It depends".

First, `os.Remove()` is a filesystem-level operation; it modifies directory entries on a filesystem and has no idea about how many open file descriptors the file to be removed may have in the process it was called in.
Yes, you can open the same file any number of times—this is only capped by a system-imposed limit.

Also consider that on reasonably modern filesystems there exists the concept of "links" (NTFS might call them differently, and last time I checked they have several concepts for what you would call a "symbolic link pointing at a directory" on a Unix-like system), and because of this, you might open physically the same file via different pathnames, and `os.Remove` operates on pathnames.

Add to this the fact that the filesystem is a live object: between the time a file was opened by some pathname on a filesystem, and the time you're about to delete a file using that pathname, this pathname may even cease to exist (but read on).

This should assure you that no, `os.Remove` does not attempt to find and close all the `os.File` instances which are known to refer to the same file.

Second, there is a gross difference in behaviour of handling of opened files between Unix-like systems and Windows; filesystems which are [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant are required to treat any opened file in any process in the system accessing a particular filesystem as a live reference to that file.
This might not be immediately clear from the docs, but this is documented in the [`close(2)` syscall reference manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/close.html):

> If the link count of the file is 0, when all file descriptors associated with the file are closed, the space occupied by the file shall be freed and the file shall no longer be accessible.

Basically that means that even if all pathnames referencing a specific file on a filesysem were removed (and hence the file was rendered inaccessible *via the filesystem)* its data is still on the filesystem untill the last file descriptor opened to that file is closed in a running process.

This "trick" is quite often employed in Unix-only software to store temporary data:

1. A temporary file is created (usually using [`mktemp(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mktemp.html); in Go that would be [`io/ioutil.TempFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile)).
2. It is then immediately removed on the filesystem (while being kept open).
3. It is then used via the file descriptor for any amount of time.
4. When the descriptor is closed, the filesystem finally reclaims the space the file's data were occupying.

This does not work on Windows: there, it is impossible to remove an opened file, and under certain circumstances it is even impossible to rename it, so the "trick" above does not work.

So, let's reconsider the original problem using the new knowledge.

- The safest choice is probably to write a simple helper to clean up temporary files, which would look like

  ```golang
  func removeTempFile(fd *os.File) {
    for _, err := range [...]error{fd.Close(), os.Remove(fd.Name())} {
      if err != nil {
        log.Print("failed to remove temp file: ", err)
        // Note that we merely log errors, not blow up on them -
        // this is to report both errors if all operations have failed.
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  and then stick `defer removeTempFile(fd)`
  after opening each new temporary file.
- If you're sure your program will only ever run on Unix-compatible systems (Linux- and *BSD-based, Mac OS etc), you may immediately remove the temporary file and only defer closing of it.

  Note that this is obviously not going to work if you actually require
  referring that file by its name—for instance, you're passing it to some external program being executed.